# Inserting wide table in IEEE ACCESS class

Tags: tables, ieeeaccess

I inserted a wide table in the IEEE Access class but some of the elements are located out of the boarder of a column:

```
    \documentclass{ieeeaccess}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\centering
    \caption{Operation on weighted feature detectors}
    \label{tab:tabel_maxop}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{100pt}|p{25pt}|p{25pt}||p{25pt}|p{25pt}||p{25pt}|p{25pt}||p{25pt}|}
        \hline
Method1 (Original)  & 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 \\
        \hline
Method1 (Original)  & 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 \\
        \hline
        Method1 (Original)  & 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 \\
        \hline
        Method1 (Original)  & 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 \\
        \hline
        Method1 (Original)  & 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 \\
        \hline
        Method1 (Original)  & 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 \\
        \hline
        Method1 (Original)  & 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 & 16.9& 32.5 \\
        \hline        
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Although I do not see any error but the table is wide and cannot be located in one colummn:

[image]

How can I place that in the center?

Comment: you have declared a table with three `p` columns `|p{100pt}|p{25pt}|p{25pt}|`  but with 8 columns of data, hence the extra alignment tab error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle , I edited to mention the main issue.

Comment: You're using a non-standard class. If you can reproduce with a standard class, please do so. If the class is implicated, please explain how it can be obtained.

Comment: You've defined all columns with an explicit width and wider than needed. Why are you doing so? You could, e.g., use an `l` column for the first column and `l`, `c`, or `r` or package `siunitx` for the number columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tabularray`.

```latex
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-6]
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Operation on weighted feature detectors}
\label{tab:tabel_maxop}
\begin{tblr}
{
hlines,vlines,
columns={colsep=4pt},
columns={valign=m,co=-1},
rows={halign=c},
}
Method1 (Original) & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 \\
Method1 (Original) & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 \\
Method1 (Original) & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 \\
Method1 (Original) & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 \\
Method1 (Original) & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 \\
Method1 (Original) & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 \\
Method1 (Original) & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 & 16.9 & 32.5 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\EOD
\end{document}
```

[image]